# Перерисовка буфера

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Когда используешь GDI, то очень сильно нагружается процессор.
Например:

```
// функция отрисовывает картинку в буфер
UIClass::DrawBitmap()
{
  if(rebuild)// сюда заходим в самом начале и при изменении положения изображения
  {
    for(...)
      for(...)
        //огромные расчеты, учитывается картинка и все что позади неё
    // выводим на экран и сохраняем в ОП что бы постоянно не перерасчитывать изображение
  }
  else
  {
    for(...)
      for(...)
        // выводим в буфер из переменной
  }
}
.......
while(true)
{
  UI.Background.DrawBitmap();

  if(UI.ExitPassive.Hover())// таких конструкции может быть множество
  {
    UI.ExitActive.DrawBitmap();
  }
  else
    UI.ExitPassive.DrawBitmap();
}
```

Цикл отрисовывает 30 раз в секунду картинки. По идеи достаточно 1 раз отрисовать и перерисовывать только при необходимости в  данном случае при изменении UI.ExitPassive.Hover() 1 раз. Но как это сделать я не могу понять

Comment: А зачем же вы делаете перерисовку и в if() { } и в else { } ?

Comment: DrawBitmap высчитывает данные, которые идут непосредственно на экран. В if() расчитывается изображение тоесть: читается из файла и преобразуется в формат 0xAARRGGBB - здесь учитывается задний фон(точнее то что уже нарисовано - находится в буфере)так как если картинка будет полупрозрачная то нужно будет перемножать её на задний фон с учетом альфы. И все это отправляется на экрна. Все это сохраняется в переменную, что бы постоянно не перерасчитывать, а только при изменении заднего фона(перемещение вращение и т.д.)

Comment: В else расчетов уже не каких нет, просто из переменной копируется в буфер данные на экран. Такой оптимизацией я снизил нагрузку цп с 25 до 10% на win 10. Но можно еще снизить, если не все 30 раз отрисовывать, а только при необходимости. Размер экрана не меняется у программы поэтому задача еще упрощается

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понял, что вам надо перерисовывать только если `UI.ExitPassive.Hover()` изменилось?
Если так, то вам надо сохранять предыдущее значение в какую-нибудь переменную типа bool например.

```
if(UI.ExitPassive.Hover() != prevHover) {
    UI.Background.DrawBitmap();
    if(UI.ExitPassive)
        UI.ExitActive.DrawBitmap();
    else
        UI.ExitPassive.DrawBitmap();
    prevHover = UI.ExitPassive.Hover();
}
```

Comment: =) не все так просто друг мой. Задний фон, предположим так уж и быть из одной картинки состоит, но он находится у многих элементов, т.е. для наглядности: как только он перепишет здесь - то в аналогичной конструкции все будет перекрыто этим задним фоном

Comment: Так вы поправьте вопрос, из вашего вопроса вообще не понятно что вы делаете, когда, как и что вам надо перерисовывать!

Comment: Вопрос надо как можно меньше раз отрисовывать, т.е. 1 раз, и перерисовывать при необходимости, в данном случае при UI.ExitPassive.Hover() == true 1 раз и UI.ExitPassive.Hover() == false, только при смене состояния.

Comment: @helldrg мой ответ удовлетворяет вашему условию в точности в той формулировке в которой вы написали.

Comment: добавьте еще одну конструкцию и вы поймете, что не правы

Comment: В реальности 3 картинки не используют в программе а по меньшей мере несколько 10 в самых простых приложениях

Comment: Я ещё раз акцентирую ваше внимание на том, что мой ответ подходит при той формулировке которую вы написали выше. Если есть какие-то ещё конструкции (какие?), вы о них ничего не упомянули.

Comment: Возможно я описал вопрос не достаточно хорошо, я готов его корректировать по мере необходимости, в данный момент наглядно видно какие конструкции:
if(UI.ExitPassive.Hover())// таких конструкции может быть множество
  {
    UI.ExitActive.DrawBitmap();
  }
  else
    UI.ExitPassive.DrawBitmap();

Comment: Теперь более-менее понятно.

Comment: Если надо еще, что то пояснить пишите, ведь действительно отсюда мало чего понятно, но я старался как мог описать проблему по понятней

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете единожды отрисовать всё содержимое в bitmap, и потом использовать его там где вы рисуете background. После этого вы можете перерисовывать только изменившиеся части общей картинки в тот же самый битмэп.

Comment: Дело в том, что фон тоже надо перезаписывать, а если его перезаписывать то он перекрывает все элементы

Comment: У вас фон ТОЖЕ каждый раз разный, или что?

Comment: один и тот же, я не знаю с чем это связано, но он портится когда над ним перерисовывается картинка. Я подозреваю что это из за альфа канала. Тем не менее если его перезаписывать то все в порядке выглядит. Идеально сделать так: Когда элемент изменяется все картинки перезаписать один раз, но у меня не получается так

Comment: Все видимые картинки